# I would like to add children to a template using get => ContentStack.Children; but this does not work properly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a template frame that provides some padding and accepts multiple elements:

```
[Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Contents")]
public class ContentFrame : StackLayout
{
    public StackLayout ContentStack = new StackLayout();
    public IList<View> Contents { get => ContentStack.Children; }

    public ContentFrame()
    {
        CustomFrame cf = new CustomFrame()
        {
            Content = ContentStack,
            HasShadow = false,
        };
        cf.SetDynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, "ContentFrameBackgroundColor");
        cf.SetDynamicResource(Frame.CornerRadiusProperty, "ContentFrameCornerRadius");
        cf.SetDynamicResource(MarginProperty, "ContentFrameMargin");
        this.Children.Add(cf);
    }
```

I would like to add child labels like this: c1.Children.Add -  But when I do this the BackgroundColor, CornerRadius and Margin don't get used (see first part of image for ABC and ABC)

The only way I can get it to use these is by exposing ContentStack as a public property and by adding to that (see below for ABC and GHI)

```
public class TestPage : HeadingView
{
    public TestPage() : base()
    {
        var s = new Stack();

        var c1 = new ContentFrame();
        c1.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "ABC" });
        c1.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "DEF" });

        var c2 = new ContentFrame();
        c2.ContentStack.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "DEF" });
        c2.ContentStack.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "GHI" });

        s.Children.Add(c1);
        s.Children.Add(c2);

        this.InnerContent = s;
    }
}
```

**Question >** Can anyone explain why the first case (with get => ContentStack.Children) doesn't show the frame background, radius etc.

[image]

Comment: the first case is adding to the outer stacklayout (outside the frame), the 2nd case is adding to the inner stacklayout (inside the frame)

Comment: Oh I see now.  Can you suggest a way that I could fix this problem and have them both add to the inner stacklayout? I can understand what you have said but I am not sure how to change it.  The end result I would like is to not have to make ContentStack public.

Comment: I would just create an `Add` method on the class that does what you want

Comment: Are you suggesting a method that would allow me to remove this ".ContentStack.Children." ?   Can you give an example of what you mean.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, ContentStack does not need to be public.  Add a public method that will handle that inner logic for you.  You can also allow it to accept multiple controls and add them all at once.

Comment: @Jason - if you have some time can you give an example and I would be happy to accept.

Answer (score 0):

make `ContentStack` private and add a method to expose the add functionality

```
private StackLayout ContentStack = new StackLayout();

public void Add(View view)
{
  this.ContentStack.Children.Add(view);
}
```

if you want to add multiple you could also do

```
public void Add(List<View> views)
{
  foreach(var v in views) 
  {
    this.ContentStack.Children.Add(v);
  }
}
```